# How to cast UTF-8 xml to SQL Xml?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net

I get XML encoded as UTF-8 in Base64 String.
First i decode from Base64 to byte then i use System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(XMLDoc) to get xml as string.
All is ok but then i must use this xml as XML in t-sql.
Xml in sql is represented by Unicode.
And when i try cast this nvarchar as XML in SQL i get error like 'XML parsing: line 4, character 32, illegal xml character'
VB:

```
  Dim XmlasBytes() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(dokBase64)
  Dim XMLasString As String = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(XmlasBytes)
  Dim XmlIn As XElement = <Param><TEST><%= XMLasString %></TEST></Param>
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc nvarchar(max)
SET @XMLDoc = @XML_IN.value('(Param/TEST)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
SELECT CAST(@XMLDoc AS XML)
```

Comment: You're not showing the code where you pass the XML value to SQL Server. The internal encoding of SQL Server for XML should be of no consequence if you're using parameters properly. And what is the contents of `XMLasString`?

Comment: I would go for a table valued parameter in sql which contains the xml column. You could than create and fill a DataTable with your xml and send it e.g. via a stored procudure or DataAdapter as dynamic parameter.